# How do you insert a python string into a link tag html

Tags: pyscript

I’m trying to make a scraper project that takes links and displays on a html page but you can’t use html tags in pyscript tag.
Is there any way to do it
What I find with printing the link is that it gives the literal string of the link and not a clickable link
This isn’t the actual code but acts as an an example of the problem

```
   <py-script>
    Var= ‘Link’
    </py-script>
    <body>
    <a href=link>Link</a>
    </body>
```

Comment: Edit your question to show the code you are having a problem with. Tip: you cannot create HTML elements by printing strings. You must call the browser DOM functions **createElement()** and family of functions to create/append HTML elements.

Comment: I’ve just added a code snippet

Answer (score 0):

You have created a clickable anchor tag. Move your mouse over the text and click it.

The problem is that the **pyscript.css** file is overwriting the attributes of some HTML tags changing how they appear. Remove pyscript.css from your program and notice the difference.

You could add your own CSS and make the Anchor Element appear how you want. To write serious PyScript programs you will need to learn about the browser DOM, CSS, etc.